# Redefinition error when using ifndef when alias is defined like "const int alias = variable" instead of #define

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, ifndef

I defined `const UInt8 HE = he;` inside `namespace Ports` in `ports.h`. Then I included it in `ports_logic.h` and in `ports_logic.h`, I have the following code inside `namespace Ports`

```
#ifndef HP
const UInt8 HP = hp;
#endif
```

However during compilation, it gives me the following error.

[image]

What is the alternative to `ifndef` that can help me check if the `const int HP` has already been defined?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you ifdeffing the whole content of ports.h? Like
`#ifndef __PORTS_H__
#define __PORTS_H__
<whole content of your ports.h file>
#endif`
BTW, you typed `ports_logic.h and in ports_logic.h`.

Comment: inline int try with this

Answer (score 5):

Briefly, `const UInt8 HP = hp;` does not introduce a pre-processor identifier on which `#ifndef HP` could ever react on.

Identifiers defined through `#define` preprocessor directive and the definition of variables are two different things. Preprocessor directives are expanded *before* the compiler analyses the code and identifies variables, functions, etc. Therefore, the definition of a variable cannot `#define` an identifier for the preprocessor, since preprocessing has already taken place at this moment.

You could overcome this by writing...

```
#ifndef HP_VAR
  #define HP_VAR
  const UInt8 HP = hp;
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing the preprocessor and the compiler. Declaring a C++ variable does not define anything in the preprocessor. Let's look line-by-line:

```
#ifndef HP
```

This is handled by the preprocessor. The only way for this to fail is by `#define HP` or similar. The C++ compiler never sees this line.

```
const UInt8 HP = hp;
```

This is handled by the C++ compiler *after* the preprocessor has done its thing. The preprocessor ignores this line.

There is no direct way to do what you want; the ideal solution is to arrange your project in a way that `HP` will never be declared more than once. It should be declared in a single translation unit, and exposed as `extern` in header files.